# How to clone splistitem in library with all metadata?

Tags: server

In my project, I have to clone some specific file and rename it with adding a prefix "Copy-".

For example:

```
original:  itemA, itemB, itemC
Now:       itemA, itemB, itemC, Copy-itemA
```

So, I tried the following code to move the file between the same library and folder.

```
  SPFile cloneFile= doc.File;
  moveFile.MoveTo(Path.Combine(originalItem.Url, "Copy" + fileName ));
```

It fails! It just replaces my original file with the name "Copy-XXXX" :(

```
original:  itemA, itemB, itemC
Now:       Copy-itemA, itemB, itemC,
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **File.CopyTo** instead of **File.MoveTo** as MoveTo function removes the existing file and creates the new one whereas the CopyTo function will give you a copy of a file . then you can update the metadata of the file.

Comment: What column(s) will be changed in file.copyTo? Name, id, Modified,Modified By.. anymore?

Comment: the file will be copied to the location specified and yes , the default fields CreatedBy , ModifedBy , Created , Modified will be updated to the current values . and other custom metadata fields can be updated as per our requirements

Comment: greeting, do you have any idea to get the ID of the clone item?